# Synchronyze SVN Repository with anonymous user

Tags: svn, synchronization, svnsync

I need to synchronize a svn repository, I know I can do this with svnsync, but the problem is that I need to do the commits to the slave repository with another user, so the svn info on master repository it is not included into the slave but being able to retrieve slave repository changes with svn log/diff.

Is there a way to do this or I have to create a shell script to achive this?

If having to do it with a shell script my idea is the following:

```
0) create a daily cronjob
1) make a diff of files between master and slave
2) svn add / del of the the different files in the slave
3) rsync master to slave
4) commit all files
```

Answer (score 1):

Vendor branching?

Just mount "master" as external into "slave" and merge

Comment: Seems to be. I catch the drive but I'm quite newbie to svn, could you be a little more specific, some command guidelines please? another thing is, can I do it without replication? just to avoid deploying 2  servers. Thanks!

Comment: seems that merging does not include changes in svn info, so it's not what i was looking for. thanks anyway